# Update ROLLEDBACK after em.MERGE JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

**Hi guys**. I get a problem, when i try to merge my entity.
I resolve object entity with new field "Name" from rest service by put request.
I tryed to merge entity with new "name" field to my database, but i got rollback after update operation, maybe you know why??
Here is my Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updDep", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
      @ResponseBody
      public String updDeps(@RequestBody Department department ) {
        departmentService.addDepartment(department);
        System.out.println("after merge;  in controller");
        return "Success";
    }
```

And  Department Service class with addDepartment() method:

```
@Repository
public class DepartmentServiceImpl implements  DepartmentService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MyPersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManager entityManager;
....
//getter/setter entityManager....
...
@Override
@Transactional
public void updDepartment(Department department) {
    Department department1 = findById(department.getId());
    department1.setName(department.getName());
    /*  NOT WORKS TOO, STILL ROOLBAKED!
    Department managedDep =  getEntityManager().merge(department);   
    managedDep.setName(department.getName());
    */
}
```

Project Structure:
[image]

**PERSISTENCE.XML**

```
 <persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testbd"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
            <!--<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value= "import.sql"/>-->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**SPRING CONFIG**

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="epam.rest" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />

    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
         <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MyPersistenceUnit"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />
</beans>
```

**LOG4J LOG:**

```
11:55:42,672 TRACE DefaultFlushEntityEventListener:281 - Updating entity: [epam.rest.entity.Department#1]
11:55:42,681 DEBUG Collections:190 - Collection found: [epam.rest.entity.Department.worker#1], was: [epam.rest.entity.Department.worker#1] (initialized)
11:55:42,682 TRACE AbstractFlushingEventListener:242 - Processing unreferenced collections
11:55:42,682 TRACE AbstractFlushingEventListener:254 - Scheduling collection removes/(re)creates/updates
11:55:42,682 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:118 - Flushed: 0 insertions, 1 updates, 0 deletions to 4 objects
11:55:42,683 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:125 - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 1 collections
11:55:42,683 DEBUG EntityPrinter:114 - Listing entities:
11:55:42,684 DEBUG EntityPrinter:121 - epam.rest.entity.Worker{id=2, department=epam.rest.entity.Department#1, salary=1200, fio=Kozlovich Andrei Vicktorovich}
11:55:42,684 DEBUG EntityPrinter:121 - epam.rest.entity.Worker{id=1, department=epam.rest.entity.Department#1, salary=1000, fio=Gabriel Alexei Nicolaevich}
11:55:42,684 DEBUG EntityPrinter:121 - epam.rest.entity.Worker{id=3, department=epam.rest.entity.Department#1, salary=1500, fio=Baym Alena Nicolaevna}
11:55:42,686 DEBUG EntityPrinter:121 - epam.rest.entity.Department{id=1, name=IT123, worker=[epam.rest.entity.Worker#2, epam.rest.entity.Worker#3, epam.rest.entity.Worker#1]}
11:55:42,687 TRACE AbstractFlushingEventListener:327 - Executing flush
11:55:42,697 TRACE AbstractEntityPersister:3166 - Updating entity: [epam.rest.entity.Department#1]
11:55:42,698 TRACE AbstractServiceRegistryImpl:146 - Initializing service [role=org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.spi.BatchBuilder]
11:55:42,704 TRACE AbstractServiceRegistryImpl:146 - Initializing service [role=org.hibernate.service.jmx.spi.JmxService]
11:55:42,706 TRACE BatchBuilderImpl:68 - Building batch [size=1]
11:55:42,708 DEBUG SQL:104 - 
    update
        departments 
    set
        name=? 
    where
        id=?
11:55:42,710 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:319 - Registering statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@646b0e6a: update departments set name=** NOT SPECIFIED ** where id=** NOT SPECIFIED **]
11:55:42,710 TRACE AbstractEntityPersister:2780 - Dehydrating entity: [epam.rest.entity.Department#1]
11:55:42,712 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - IT123
11:55:42,713 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 1
11:55:42,714 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:358 - Releasing statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@646b0e6a: update departments set name='IT123' where id=1]
11:55:42,715 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:476 - Closing prepared statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@646b0e6a: update departments set name='IT123' where id=1]
11:55:42,715 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:249 - Starting after statement execution processing [ON_CLOSE]
11:55:42,717 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:249 - Starting after statement execution processing [ON_CLOSE]
11:55:42,718 DEBUG AbstractTransactionImpl:203 - rolling back
11:55:42,786 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:164 - rolled JDBC Connection
11:55:42,787 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:126 - re-enabling autocommit
11:55:42,788 TRACE TransactionCoordinatorImpl:136 - after transaction completion
11:55:42,792 TRACE SessionImpl:624 - after transaction completion
11:55:42,794 TRACE SessionImpl:342 - Closing session
11:55:42,795 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:171 - Closing JDBC container [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl@6583023d]
11:55:42,796 DEBUG JdbcCoordinatorImpl:173 - HHH000420: Closing un-released batch
11:55:42,797 TRACE LogicalConnectionImpl:164 - Closing logical connection
11:55:42,797 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:232 - Releasing JDBC connection
11:55:42,798 TRACE DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:233 - Returning connection to pool, pool size: 1
11:55:42,799 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:250 - Released JDBC connection
11:55:42,799 TRACE LogicalConnectionImpl:176 - Logical connection closed
```

**WORKER ENTITY**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "workers")
public class Worker {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String fio;

    @ManyToOne(cascade =  {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Department department;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer salary;
......
```

**DEPARTMENT ENTITY**

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="departments")
public class Department implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade =  {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "department")
    private Set<Worker> worker;
.......
```

TELL ME PLS WHAT I DID WRONG?!

**UPDATE 1**
I updated my code
1)delete persistence.xml
2)remove (unitName = "MyPersistenceUnit") in services:

```
 @PersistenceContext
 private EntityManager entityManager;
```

2)edit despatcher-servlet.xml:
Now it is look like that:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="epam.rest" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />

    </bean>


    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="epam.rest.entity" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />

    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />
</beans>
```

But when i try to update, i still got the same ROLLEDBACK

```
04:14:06,765 TRACE AbstractEntityPersister:3166 - Updating entity: [epam.rest.entity.Department#1]
04:14:06,766 TRACE AbstractServiceRegistryImpl:146 - Initializing service [role=org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.spi.BatchBuilder]
04:14:06,772 TRACE AbstractServiceRegistryImpl:146 - Initializing service [role=org.hibernate.service.jmx.spi.JmxService]
04:14:06,774 TRACE BatchBuilderImpl:68 - Building batch [size=1]
04:14:06,776 DEBUG SQL:104 - update departments set name=? where id=?
04:14:06,777 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:319 - Registering statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@3918a7aa: update departments set name=** NOT SPECIFIED ** where id=** NOT SPECIFIED **]
04:14:06,778 TRACE AbstractEntityPersister:2780 - Dehydrating entity: [epam.rest.entity.Department#1]
04:14:06,779 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - IT21
04:14:06,780 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 1
04:14:06,782 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:358 - Releasing statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@3918a7aa: update departments set name='IT21' where id=1]
04:14:06,783 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:476 - Closing prepared statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@3918a7aa: update departments set name='IT21' where id=1]
04:14:06,783 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:249 - Starting after statement execution processing [ON_CLOSE]
04:14:06,785 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:249 - Starting after statement execution processing [ON_CLOSE]
04:14:06,785 DEBUG AbstractTransactionImpl:203 - rolling back
04:14:06,856 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:164 - rolled JDBC Connection
04:14:06,857 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:126 - re-enabling autocommit
04:14:06,858 TRACE TransactionCoordinatorImpl:136 - after transaction completion
04:14:06,862 TRACE SessionImpl:624 - after transaction completion
04:14:06,866 TRACE SessionImpl:342 - Closing session
04:14:06,867 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:171 - Closing JDBC container [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl@71799400]
04:14:06,867 DEBUG JdbcCoordinatorImpl:173 - HHH000420: Closing un-released batch
04:14:06,868 TRACE LogicalConnectionImpl:164 - Closing logical connection
04:14:06,868 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:232 - Releasing JDBC connection
04:14:06,868 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:250 - Released JDBC connection
04:14:06,869 TRACE LogicalConnectionImpl:176 - Logical connection closed
```

What is wrong now?!
**UPDATE2**
I looked in my pom.xml file:

```
....
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
.....
```

So when i delete ths :

```
 <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>
```

all works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you provided two different jdbc connection info to Hibernate:

1. Through the Spring configured DataSourcw
2. Through Hibernate jdbc connection properties

Because you need to integrate Spring Transaction demarcation to Hibernate transaction logic, you can only rely on the DataSource you provided to your JPA TransactionManager.

That's why you see the auto-commit re-enabling log too.

So remove all hibernate.connection.* lines and you should be fine:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testbd"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
```

With these lines removed, Hibernate will not override the DataSource with its own internal JDBC connection provider.

Comment: Thx,but when  removed that lines, hibernate stoped to creat tables on project deploy, and import data from import.sql. Maybe i need add some hibernate xml config files in my project?

Comment: The hbmddl.auto property controls that, so your tablet should be created. Since you use update, they will only be great the first time.

Comment: I understand you.. But  it seems like hibernate  stoped read props  in persistence.xml after i removed lines from your  answer. And my mysql dtbase was cleared after i redeploy project without that lines. It seems  to me what i need to move my hbmddl.auto  and import props somewhere in my spring config xml. Sorry if I going  wrong.

Comment: The Spring entity manager factory implementation may accept those properties too.

Comment: Pls watch my UPDATE1 in my question, i still got the same problem.

Comment: Your connection release mode is set to AFTER_STATEMENT which is what Hibernate uses by default for JTA. With the current settings is not clear why Hibernate uses JTA even if you use local transactions. You'll have to debug and figure out why Hibernate doesn't use JDBCTransactionFactory instead.

Comment: MY PROBLEM WAS IN POM.XML FILE! SEE UPDATE2 IN MY QUESTION

Comment: Great! Yes you don't need that, Hibernate fetches the right dependency for the current core one.